# how to create a client/server which receive more than 2048 Characters using spring ip integration TCP

Tags: multithreading, spring-integration-ip

How to create a client/server which receive more than 2048 Characters using spring ip integration   TCP?

Comment: have you already gotten it to work with fewer-than-2048-characters?

Comment: yes, I  already did  it with less than 2048 characters

Comment: So, how about showing us what you have already done?

Comment: I use the code on Annotation-Based Configuration Paragraph,  this is the link    https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html

Comment: In that link, it says: "The default maximum message size is 2048 bytes. You can increase it by setting the maxMessageSize property. If you use the default serializer or deserializer and wish to increase the maximum message size, you must declare the maximum message size as an explicit bean with the maxMessageSize property set and configure the connection factory to use that bean."  Does this answer your question?

Comment: question is: "how to create a client/server which receive more than 2048 Characters using spring ip integration TCP".  The probleme is that, I dont now how to set the maxMessageSize propeeties; I am using the annotations config

Comment: I see. Well, I don't know either. Hopefully someone who knows will show up.